# Can't use sprint inside gensub (awk)

Tags: awk

I am new to awk and would like to change floating number precision of the number inside a string (it's 10th column in my file) by using awk:
Ex:

```
Name_1:0.123456@123
Name_1:0.123456@123Name_2:0.333564@456
Name_1:0.123456@123Name_2:0.333564@456Name_3:0.25468@895
```

What I want:

```
Name_1:0.12@123
Name_1:0.12@123Name_2:0.3@456
Name_1:0.123456@123Name_2:0.333564@456Name_3:0.25@895
```

I can have any number of "Name_".

I thought something like this:

```
awk '{$10=gensub(/(-?[0-9|.])+@/, sprintf("%.2f", "&"), "g", $10)}1'
```

But seems & isn't recognized inside sprintf.

Could you please help?

Comment: Welcome to SO and nice question. Is it really necessary to use `gensub`? Because I tried and sprintf is NOT getting taken inside `gensub` are we allowed to use field separators? Kindly do let us know.

Comment: BTW your regex for `gensub` is wrong as per your sample output it could be `awk 'BEGIN{regex="([^:]*):([^@]*)@([^:]*):([^@]*)@.*"} {print gensub(regex, "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", "1", $0)}' Input_file`, though I stick to my previous comment of using field separator :)

Comment: Without gensub: `awk -F '[:@]' '{$2=sprintf("%.2f",$2); $4=sprintf("%.2f",$4); print $1 ":" $2 "@" $3 ":" $4 "@" $5}' file`

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer, But I forgot to mention (will edit the question) that in my file there are cases when  I have more than 2 names: Name_1:0.123456@123Name_2:0.333564@456Name_3:0.568912@5486. That's why I was thinking about to have some general regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any Algol-base programming language (awk, C, Ada, pascal, whatever) when you write a statement involving 2 functions foo() and bar() like this:

```
foo(bar())
```

it means you want to pass the value returned by `bar()` into `foo()` as an argument. Given that, you can't have `bar()` take any value populated by running `foo()` as an argument because `foo()` doesn't execute until **after** `bar()` has executed.

For your particular case instead of:

```
awk '{$10=gensub(/(-?[0-9|.])+@/, sprintf("%.2f", "&"), "g", $10)}1'
```

you should use the 3rd arg to `match()` instead of `gensub()` to isolate the string you're interested in so you can populate an array with `match()` that `sprintf()` called AFTER `match()` can then operate on, i.e. instead of trying to do one of these:

```
gensub(/target/,sprintf(&))
gensub(/(xxx)(target)(yyy)/,sprintf("\\2"))
```

you'll do one of these:

```
match($0,/target/,a); sprintf(a[0])
match($0,/(xxx)(target)(yyy)/,a); sprintf(a[2])
```

Having said that, here's how to do what I think you're trying to do using any awk since the gawk-only functions don't help much for this use-case:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    rec = ""
    while ( match($0,/-?[0-9.]+@/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
        rec = rec substr($0,1,RSTART-1) sprintf("%.2f",tgt)
        $0  = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
    }
    print rec $0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Name_1:0.12@123
Name_1:0.12@123Name_2:0.33@456
Name_1:0.12@123Name_2:0.33@456Name_3:0.25@895
```